# Problems making a Toggle

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery, error-reporting

I have been making an article in Joomla, and for doing it more visually, I want to show text when I click in a li.
The problem is an error appears in the console...
I don't know if the error it's because the code I've made, JQuery EASY or JCH Optimize...
This is the code:
HTML5

```
<div class="article-part">
    <h3><strong>Servicios: (Líneas de actividad)</strong></h3>
    <ul>
        <li class="plegable"><strong>Header 1</strong>
            <p class="qs-datos">Content to expand</p>
        </li>
        <li class="plegable"><strong>Header 2</strong>
            <p class="qs-datos">Content to expand</p>
        </li>
        <li class="plegable"><strong>Header 3</strong>
            <p class="qs-datos">Content to expand</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.plegable').on('click', function(){ 
        $(this).next('.plegable > p').slideToggle(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting in the console? I've also simplified the HTML code to it's more of a dummy example that can be easily read

Comment: http://gyazo.com/6251926e320004f68bb0bb2e3010d422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, try disabling the JCH Optimize plugin to see if your code works.

If not, then try using `jQuery` as the global scope and `$` as an alias like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.plegable').on('click', function(){ 
        $(this).next('.plegable > p').slideToggle(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: It works without JCH Optimize... So... what should I do...?

Comment: Try the code I provided

Comment: Neither, it doesn't still work

Comment: It might be due to the gzip option you have enabled. Try disabling only that option

Comment: I got it disabling "minify js"; but i have to put ".plegable > strong"

Answer (score 0):

your element **.qs-datos** is **not** a next() element of the **li**
It's a **child** element in your code.

So your html should look more like this:

```
<h3 class="plegable">Header 3</h3>
<div class="qs-datos">Content to expand</div>
<h3 class="plegable">Header 3</h3>
<div class="qs-datos">Content to expand</div>
<h3 class="plegable">Header 3</h3>
<div class="qs-datos">Content to expand</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.plegable').on('click', function(){ 
        $(this).children('p').slideToggle(); 
    });
});
```